# Trouble using the back arrow key in R

Tags: linux, ssh, r

I am sshing to a linux server via ExtraPutty and am running R. If I type some code and then I hit the back arrow three times, I get the following output:

`blah blah some code^[[D^[[D^[[D`

The R console won't allow me to go backwards on a line. My arrow keys work fine when I exit R and just use C shell normally. Any ideas why this might be happening? Is it a key event forwarding issue?

Comment: Does Ctrl+B work?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (or add to it if it exists) called `.inpurc` in your home directory on the remote system and add these lines to it:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\eOd": backward-word

"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\eOc": forward-word
```

My guess (and it's just a guess) is that for some reason R is not reading the system wide `/etc/inputrc` file which is where that kind of keyboard shortcut is stored. Creating your own local copy with the needed assignments might solve it.